# How to draw bitmap and circle at the same point in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to draw bitmap and circle at the same point using the following code. But circle and bitmap drawn at different places.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(reSized, 0, 0, null);  
pcanvas.drawCircle(stDropCurPoint.x, stDropCurPoint.y, 3, mPaint);  
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,null);  
canvas.save();  
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, stDropCurPoint.x, stDropCurPoint.y, null);  
canvas.restore();
```

My bitmap "bmp" width and height are 50*50 . I am trying to draw a circle of radius 3.
 Kindly let me know how to draw circle and bitmap at the same point .
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As the bitmaps x and y coordinates refer to the top left of the image, you might want to offset it half its width and height to center it to the stDropCurPoint.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, stDropCurPoint.x - bmp.getWidth()/2, stDropCurPoint.y - bmp.getHeight()/2, null);
```